# Arduino C: program not behaving correctly without printing variable to serial monitor

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

This is one of the most bizarre errors I've ever experienced. I am using two LEDs as indicator lights for a project I am working on, a red and a green. One of the status codes I want to implement is for it to alternately flash the green LED and the red LED four times total. When I tested my implementation, it flashed the green LED first once, then the red LED three times. I wanted to make sure the loop was iterating properly, so I added `Serial.println()`'s to test that. For some reason this made the code produce the expected output. `*iter` isn't changed or modified in any way, but if I comment out that `println` the incorrect behavior resumes. Below is all of the relevant code, as tested in isolation to confirm it wasn't something else causing the problem. If anyone can tell me what is going on I would appreciate it, I am so confused right now.

```
// Function prototype probably unnecessary but being thorough
void redGreenLED (int *mode, int *iter, unsigned long *timer);

// Human-friendly pin names, using analogs as digital because every
// single pin I can use is being used for this project
const int pinG = A2;
const int pinR = A3;

// Global variables for LED control
int rgMode = 0;
unsigned long rgTimer = 0;
int rgIter = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  // assign I/O
  pinMode(pinG, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinR, OUTPUT);

  // delay for convenience
  delay(1500);

  // flash red and green alternately 4 times
  rgMode = 1;
}

void loop() {
  redGreenLED(&rgMode, &rgIter, &rgTimer);
}

void redGreenLED (int *mode, int *iter, unsigned long *timer) {
  if (*mode == 1) {
    // Alternately flash red and green for 100 ms four times
    if (*iter < 8) {
      if (!(*iter % 2) && !(*iter % 4) && (millis() - *timer) > 75) {
        Serial.println(*iter); // Why does this being included make a difference???
        digitalWrite(pinG, HIGH);
        *timer = millis();
        *iter += 1;
      } else if (!(*iter % 2) && (millis() - *timer) > 75) {
        digitalWrite(pinR, HIGH);
        *timer = millis();
        *iter += 1;
      } else if ((*iter % 2) && (millis() - *timer) > 100) {
        digitalWrite(pinR, LOW);
        digitalWrite(pinG, LOW);
        *timer = millis();
        *iter += 1;
      }
    } else {
      *iter = 0;
      *mode = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unexplained changes in behavior of code based on the addition or removal of any seemingly unrelated code is usually evidence that your code is exhibiting *undefined behavior*. It is impossible to tell where in the snippet (or elsewhere) that may be occurring without a [A Minimal Complete Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also rather than an equation based selection of red or green, simply create a global `int color = 0;` and in a `flash_red_green()` function display red if `color == 0` and green if `color == 1` and toggle the value of `color`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I appreciate the suggestion on a better way of alternating, that should work well, thank you. As for an MRE, the above code is an MRE (insofar as code meant for a single family of hardware is reproducible). Paste the above code into a .ino file and upload it to an Arduino (with LEDs at the correct pins) and you should get the same result (I tested this exact code with a second Arduino Uno I had lying around). The fact that this behavior occurs with this simple MRE is why it's so baffling; if it was happening only in my original spaghetti of a project I wouldn't be so surprised.

Comment: Perhaps timing is an issue. I notice that you keep reading `millis()` rather than reading it *once* per cycle into a variable.

Comment: @JohnDoe sorry about the MRE suggestion if that is complete. I've done work with just about every other embedded chip but not Arduino (though I have borrowed ideas from the code). KISS philosophy is always best. A toggle between two states is a great simplification. I second Weather Vane's suggestion about timings. If adding `Serial.println(..)` helps, then that may be injecting just enough additional delay to make the loop timing happy. I'd start by rewriting the red_green function and simplify the logic and the timings and see if that helps.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That turned out to be exactly it. I found that adding a 4ms delay did the trick. I wonder *why* that is the case? But, it works and isn't dependent on the serial monitor so I'm satisfied. Thanks for the help. Plus, I've implemented the toggle method for this and the other alternating modes, much more simple, thanks for that too.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Loop timings are finicky (as you have found) - avoid them at all costs. Instead, get in the habit of using interrupts, interval timers or one-shot timers to handle timed events. My *GUESS* is there is some timing issue with `millis() - *timer` and then the immediate `*timer = millis();` that prevents your comparisons from testing true as you anticipate.  Impossible for me to know, but if you have a software logic analyzer you can look to see if the gpio pins are doing what you think at the intervals you expect. Keep it simple and good luck with your coding!

Comment: Not related to the problem you are facing, but looking at your code on `redGreenLED(&rgMode, &rgIter, &rgTimer);` and `redGreenLED (int *mode, int *iter, unsigned long *timer)`, maybe you should learn [pass by reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cpp-functions-pass-by-reference/).